# How to loop through a list using indexes/indices in drools file

Tags: java, drools, rule-engine

I had a requirement to loop through a list using indices in drools file because I wanted to compare an value in the list to its next value in the list. One way was to use `from` keyword to get individual list items but I needed indices too

```
 value : String() from $listOfString
```

Answer (score 1):

solved it by accessing the list in when, and for-looping through it in then clause

```
rule "Iterate and compare"
when
    $list : ArrayList()
then
  for (int i = 0; i < $list.size(); i++) {
    if (list.get(i) comapred to list.get(i+1)) {
        // insert/aggregate the result
    }
  }
end
```

Comment: By doing it in the then-clause you've lost all of the performance optimization drools provides.

Comment: @RoddyoftheFrozenPeas then how do you propose we handle such a case where index of the element is also needed

Comment: Personally I'd use an Iterator, or change the structure of the inputs to working memory to not include a List but some more appropriate type based on the actual use case. (Also your code will throw an IndexOutOfBoundsException when `i` is the last index.)

Comment: Iterator seems a good direction. I'll try and get back.